# App invite in google plus

Tags: android, google-app-invites

I am using App Invite API of Google. It is working properly. But the problem is, when I send app invite from the Sample application provided by Google itself, the view in the mail is different. Please have a look on the following image.

But when I invite friend from my own application, View in mail is quite different.

I am not why it is happening on my end. Is that view custom developed by Google ? If it is, How does google link that view with its application?

[image]

Comment: Unless you're using Gmail as your email client, it probably has something to do with the email client you're using.
Also note, that this feature is in beta - you might just've stumbled upon an (un)known bug in the framework.

Comment: It may be some bug in the API but how is google linking that gmail view thru it's application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as expected. The email fills out it's data from the Play Store data. In the first case, the sample app has an entry in the play store so displays that data, but your testing app must not have a Play Store entry to retrieve. Once you have uploaded your app to the Play Store it should work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you very much to both who asked question and answer, I was looking for the same question and now I got my answer. I almost spent so many days to get this information posted on email like description, rating, review count etc but not getting as my app is not on play store.